# 2 SSDs to one partition

Tags: mac, ssd

I have the same external SSD twice. I would like to save the macOS operating system on these two SSDs so that the operating system recognizes the 2 SSDs as one SSD.

About the same as with a FusionDrive, only the difference is not 1x HDD and 1x SSD but 2x SSD. But this should be a startup volume.  So what I can start with.

My thought: Create a JBOD in recoveryOS Install macOS on it and boot on it is that possible?

How do I get it that way?

Thanks

Comment: Joining two SSDs into a RAID 0 setup to boot from duplicates the risk of experiencing a critical failure (if one SSD breaks the whole RAID most likely goes down). It might be better to boot from one, mount the other and then just use symlinks to offload part of your /Users folder.

Comment: We don’t boot off our RAID, so you would want to test that in a free trial before buying what I recommend. Have you tested your system, it might be faster to boot from one drive and move storage to another. RAID gives you write penalty almost always in practice despite benchmarks on theoretical write showing faster.

Comment: Yeah: booting from a RAID set might not be possible, or at best problematic. If both drives aren't instantly available at the same time, then you'll have trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do this at work all the time with SoftRaid and NVMe M.2 storage. We have never had a case where booting from RAID paid off performance wise, but I’ll take your requirements as having merit.

- https://www.softraid.com/softraid-big-sur-and-the-new-m1-macs/
- https://www.owcdigital.com/products/express-4m2

Remember, raid is not backup. There are many vendors and you generally get the support you pay for. OWC has been by our side for a very long time, so start with them if you struggle to pick a vendor that will support you. You can start with any commodity SSD and stripe them with Apple Disk Utility, but getting better RAID options is low cost and high return for us.

Comment: SoftRAID have now removed the "Lite" package, so is now considerably more expensive if you just want RAID 0 or 1.

Comment: You are correct @benwiggy the lite version is free for OWC hardware customers and if you don't get that license, paying for pro is required past a 14 day free trial. For the pro side, it’s 10x cheaper than the other solutions we roll out like promise or SAN solutions. I think there are better avenues to achieve faster storage for home users than this method, but that would be an answer for a different question perhaps.

Comment: I was using the Lite app for my G-RAID, @bmike but now I'm on Big Sur, I'll have to decommission the drive, instead of paying $200 'upgrade'.

Comment: Ouch @benwiggy That's a lot for someone that isn't making $200 an hour billing clients with jobs that use their Mac let alone us who employ dozens of people (minimum) working per client. For us it's not worth having a meeting to discuss spending less than $250 on a one shot license - that goes on the monthly expense report. Can I edit this post to make it more useful or a +1? (and if it's really wrong -1)

Answer (score 5):

Only two drives would have to be RAID 0.
This is the least safe RAID type of all. Plus it would have to be software, not hardware RAID, so even less stable.

I wouldn't trust it as far as I could spit it, because the first time one of the drives glitches or doesn't hook up to USB just exactly properly first attempt, all your data is gone forever.

After the question edit - trying to make a Fusion drive using two identical speed drives makes absolutely no sense at all. A Fusion drive uses a small SSD as a fast cache to a larger HDD.